# Running Function on all Items in a List (Converting List of Dates to Unix Timestamp)

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I'm stuck trying to figure out what is wrong with my for loop.  Why is this appending the same UNIX timestamp in all of the UNIX dates variable?

```
now = datetime.datetime.today()
dates = []
for x in range(7):
    d = now - timedelta(days=x)
    dates.append(d.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
print(dates)
unixdates = []
for date in dates:
    e = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), '%m/%d/%Y').timetuple())
    unixdates.append(e)
print(unixdates)
```

Here is the output:

```
['2021/11/03', '2021/11/02', '2021/11/01', '2021/10/31', '2021/10/30', '2021/10/29', '2021/10/28']
[1635912000.0, 1635912000.0, 1635912000.0, 1635912000.0, 1635912000.0, 1635912000.0, 1635912000.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you use the same date over and over again which will always give the same UNIX time (`datetime.date.today()`, with `datetime` being the datetime module here).

simplify your code by using the [datetime.timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method to get UNIX time:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now().date()
dates, unixdates = [], []

for x in range(7):
    d = today - timedelta(days=x)
    dates.append(d.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
    unixdates.append(datetime.combine(d, datetime.min.time()).timestamp())

print(dates)
print(unixdates) # my machine is on UTC+1
# ['2021/11/03', '2021/11/02', '2021/11/01', '2021/10/31', '2021/10/30', '2021/10/29', '2021/10/28']
# [1635894000.0, 1635807600.0, 1635721200.0, 1635631200.0, 1635544800.0, 1635458400.0, 1635372000.0]
```

Also notice that you use [naive datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) here, which will assume local time if you don't set the tz argument, e.g.

```
today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

to get UTC.

Comment: Wow thank you.  This works like a charm